# Trouble getting JSON from Github

Tags: ajax, json, git

I am still learning how to pull information cross-domain, let alone AJAX/JSON and I am having trouble getting a JSON file from github. (never done this before)

I have been reading about security issues with cross-domain and I am trying to fix this by using `header` or `jsonp` but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my attempt thus far (new to this, sorry if it is a bad attempt)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var ID = "aanders50/0c190f846790c9b05691";
   $.ajax({
       url: 'https://gist.github.com/'+ID,
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { 
       },
       headers: {
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
       },
       success: function (json) {
           alert(JSONurl = 'https://gist.github.com/' + ID);
           alert(json[ID].id);
           alert(json[ID].name);
           alert(json[ID].summonerLevel); 
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("error");
       }
   });
});
```

I have been searching for awhile now but I feel like I am missing something that I cannot find, which makes it hard to actually search for an answer.. :(

**The errors**
[image]

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://gist.github.com/aanders50/0c190f846790c9b05691. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:56087' is therefore not allowed access.

GET http://localhost:56087/1f950c50642c41cfa5690a661fc548db/arterySignalR/ping?…http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A56087%2FEvents&browserName=Chrome&_=1405009417830 404 (Not Found)
```

**The Git File**
[image]
**[The File](https://gist.github.com/aanders50/0c190f846790c9b05691)**

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been reading about security issues with cross-domain and I am trying to fix this by using header or jsonp but nothing seems to be working.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. It would be rather pointless if you could grant yourself permission to read data from a server. You can't set response headers for the URL you are using because you don't control the server; Github do.

You can't use JSONP. The document you are requesting is an HTML document, not a JSONP script. (Note that this also means you can't parse it as JSON).

If you want to fetch the page, then you'll need to use a proxy (e.g. make the Ajax request to your own server and have it fetch the data for you).

Comment: Is there anyway to use some public (off site) location to store a JSON that people can modify and that my AJAX can pull from? Or does it all have to be within my own directory?

Comment: There is actually a [gist API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist) that might work for you, but mind the [rate limiting](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)

Comment: I'm not aware of any such service. It would be expensive to run and have little in the way of revenue potential. You could run your own service that allows people to upload JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

Your file https://gist.github.com/aanders50/0c190f846790c9b05691 needs to support jsonp and return a JSON response for you to use it outside this domain.

Simply adding headers to your AJAX request will not help here.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that with gist, or another site to store an editable JSON file that will allow those options?

Comment: Not if you are using AJAX. In that case you need to host the file on the same server.